# Using relationship in laravel models how to get the data in blade file?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am querying data from database with two tables.

1. Loads:

   - LoadId
   - OriginStopId
   - DestStopId
2. Stops:

   - id
   - City
   - State
   - loadId

A Load could have multiple stops but a stop has one load. A load has minimum two stops the origin and the destination.

I have created the models as

```
class LoadsModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'loads';
    public function stops(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Stops');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Stops extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'stops';
   public function loads(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\LoadsModel');
   }
}
```

I am using the model to pass the model into the view.

```
  public function index()
  {
      $loads = LoadsModel::orderBy('loadId')->get();
      return view('tender.available')->with(['loads'=>$loads]);
  }
```

I want to show the result in a blade as according to the table headers where the Origin city is the origin city of the stop whose id is the same as the originstopId in loads table and Destination city of the stop whose id is the destStopId in loads table. I want to show the counts of the stops of a load. Something like this .

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
       <th>Origin City</th>
       <th>Origin State</th>
       <th>Destination City</th>
       <th>Destination State</th>
       <th>Load Id</th>
       <th>Stops</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Loop over your `$loads` variable, like `@foreach($loads AS $load)`, and access the property you want to display, like `{{ $load->id }}`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a foreach loop to access every attribute from each load:

```
@foreach($loads as $load)
 <tr>
     <th>{{$load->id}}</th>
              .
              .
              .
     <th>{{$load->anyAttributeYouWant}}</th>

     @foreach($load->stops as $stop)
         <th>{{$stop->id}}</th>
         <th>{{$stop->city}}</th>
         <th>{{$stop->state}}</th>
     @endforeach
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

I've made a foreach in your stops relation too, so you can show all the atributes from the stops.

You could count the stops from a load using the `withCount` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships):

```
public function index()
{
    $loads = LoadsModel::orderBy('loadId')->withCount('stops')->get();
    return view('tender.available')->with(['loads'=>$loads]);
}
```

You can access the count in your view like this:

```
{{$load->stops_count}}
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. I also had to change the primary key and set the foreign key in the belongsTo method. But it worked. Thanks again.